# Haskell removeDirectoryRecursive: permission denied on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell

When I use [`removeDirectoryRecursive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.7.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:removeDirectoryRecursive) on Windows, an `IOException` of type `PermissionDenied` is thrown with the message “removeDirectoryRecursive: permission denied”. I do have the required permissions to remove the directory. This issue does not occur on Linux for a directory with identical contents.

Comment: you can't remove a directory that's not empty...

Comment: @MarcB: That is why `removeDirectoryRecursive` is _recursive_: it recursively deletes all contents before deleting the directory. I know what the issue is, and I shared the solution here [Q&A style](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help other people who might encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the directory to be removed contains files that are read-only, removing those will fail on Windows but not on Linux.

There exists [`removePathForcibly`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.7.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:removePathForcibly), but it was only introduced [very recently](https://github.com/haskell/directory/issues/59#issuecomment-237458410).

So here’s a little helper function to recursively make files writable. It can be used before calling `removeDirectoryRecursive`.

```
import Control.Monad (forM_, when)
import System.FilePath ((</>))
import qualified System.Directory as FileSystem

-- Recursively makes all files and directories in a directory writable.
-- On Windows this is required to be able to recursively delete the directory.
makeWritableRecursive :: FilePath -> IO ()
makeWritableRecursive path = do
  permissions <- FileSystem.getPermissions path
  FileSystem.setPermissions path (FileSystem.setOwnerWritable True permissions)
  isDirectory <- FileSystem.doesDirectoryExist path
  when isDirectory $ do
    contents <- FileSystem.listDirectory path
    forM_ [path </> item | item <- contents] makeWritableRecursive
```